# How catch update google sheets and send to python?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gspread

I can insert date from python to google sheets.
How can I make reverse, catch update google sheets data and send to python ?

Maybe it can be done in google scripts or using ApiHooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this data to be transferred to a server you could use an event trigger with that Google Sheet file. The event will be triggered when the sheet is edited (documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) and you can capture information about the change with Apps Script. This data can be submitted with a HTTP request either with GET or POST using URLFetch (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) to a server if you have your data there.

Alternatively you can capture data locally by using the Google Sheets API. Let me know if you need more details so I can update the answer.